# Paypal Rest API Working with Demo Account but not with Live Account

Tags: c#, paypal

I use below code for Paypal Rest API to Store Credit Card Information

```
            String AccessToken = "";
            PaypalAccessToken pat = new PaypalAccessToken();
            AccessToken = pat.GetPaypalAccessToken();
            PayPal.Api.Payments.Address add = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Address();
            add.city = TextBoxCity.Text;
            add.line1 = TextBoxAddress.Text;
            add.phone = TextBoxPhoneNumber.Text;
            add.postal_code = TextBoxZipcode.Text;
            add.state = DropDownState.SelectedValue;
            PayPal.Api.Payments.CreditCard cc = new PayPal.Api.Payments.CreditCard();
            cc.number = TextBoxCreditCardNumber.Text;
            cc.expire_month = Convert.ToInt16(TextBoxExpiryMonth.Text);
            cc.expire_year = Convert.ToInt16(TextBoxExpiryYear.Text);
            cc.cvv2 = TextBoxCVVNumber.Text;
            cc.type = DropDownCreditCardType.SelectedValue;
            //cc.billing_address = add;

           PayPal.Api.Payments.CreditCard ResultCC = cc.Create(AccessToken);
```

This Code working good with Demo Credentials but When I try to use same with Live Credentials, It is giving me error : 401 Unauthorized. I can still get token in live credentials but I could not store credit card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal's REST API's are available globally as of the 31st of July 2013.
However, this applies only to PayPal payments. That is, setting the `payment_method` to `paypal` in the JSON payload and redirecting the buyer to PayPal.

If you want to process credit card payments, this is currently only supported in the US, UK or Canada.
You will need to enable this capability for your app via https://developer.paypal.com/ > Applications.
Note: Enabling card payments for live transactions requires a review of your account.

If you try to process card payments in live, with an account that's not enabled for it, you will get a HTTP 401 in the response from the `/payment` resource.

Comment: What happens if the payment method is an authorization and the call is from outside the US/UK/Can? Is it possible my server's calls to capture authorizations are failing because it's incorrectly identified as outside of US? I get HTTP 500 errors when I try to capture authorizations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158289

Comment: You can create and capture authorizations outside the US/UK/Canada - only the funding method (creditcard vs paypal) is restricted outside these countries. You can do auth/capture PayPal account funded payments globally.

Comment: "Enabling card payments for live transactions requires a review of your account. " About how long does this review usually take?

Comment: This typically takes a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your endpoints to use the live endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

It was something wrong with Paypal Rest ApI because its still in Beta version . They fixed it for me.